# How to loop through all the tables in database and execute a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to search that which table in my database has a record which has the given primary key. If i would have known the database, query would have been quite simple, like below

```
select * from custom.customerA where id = 'BBD87605-8992-40B5-9BEA-5C85F3969CEC'
```

But as i don't know the DB, i am trying something like below, but it's not correct.

```
select * from 'custom.'+INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables where id = 'BBD87605-8992-40B5-9BEA-5C85F3969CEC'
```

Basically i need to execute below query in all the tables in the DB.

```
select *, TableName from custom.{TABLE} where id = 'BBD87605-8992-40B5-9BEA-5C85F3969CEC'
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you are trying to do is search every table for a given value? This is extremely ugly and there is no way to do this fast. I hope this something you only need to do once in a LONG while. This code will generate a dynamic list of select statements that you can run. It will only look at columns where the datatype is uniqueidentifier.

```
DECLARE @MySearchCriteria VARCHAR(500)
SET @MySearchCriteria = '''BBD87605-8992-40B5-9BEA-5C85F3969CEC''' --you do need all these quotation marks because this string is injected to another string.

SELECT 'SELECT ' + c.columnlist + '] FROM [' + t.name + '] WHERE ' + w.whereclause  as SelectStatement
FROM sys.tables t 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF((    
        SELECT '], [' + c.Name AS [text()]
        FROM sys.columns c
        join sys.types t2 on t2.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
        WHERE t.object_id = c.object_id 
            and t2.name = 'uniqueidentifier'
        FOR XML PATH('') 
    ), 1, 2, '' )
) c (columnlist)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STUFF((    
        SELECT ' OR [' + c.Name + '] IN (' + @MySearchCriteria + ')' AS [text()]
        FROM sys.columns c
        join sys.types t2 on t2.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
        WHERE t.object_id = c.object_id 
            and t2.name = 'uniqueidentifier'
        FOR XML PATH('') 
    ), 1, 4, '' )
) w (whereclause)
where c.columnlist is not null
ORDER BY t.name
```

Comment: This query is generating the select statements. I want those select statements to be executed in the query and give me the result that which table has the search criteria.

Comment: Are you seriously going to be doing this routinely? Do you realize how horrible this would be to your system? You are basically searching every row of every table and each column with the matching datatype. It will cripple your system while this executes. I would use this to create your statements and then just select them and run them. If you want this as a fully dynamic statement I did the hard part, you should be able to execute it....might want consider getting lunch when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_MSforeachtable`. It's an undocumented stored procedure so don't use it in production:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'SELECT * FROM custom.[?] WHERE id =''BBD87605-8992-40B5-9BEA-5C85F3969CEC'''
```